# Returning variable name rather than it's value

Tags: python

```
def my_function(x, y, z):
    mini = min(x,y,z)
    return mini

a = 78*453
b = 654-877
c = 98765*785

print(my_function(a,b,c))
```

I'm learning about functions in Python, and I'm wondering how can I return the variable name rather than it's value in this code. 
I know the variable b (which is assigned to the local variable y) has the minimum value, but how can I print "b" or "y" instead of '-223' based on that?

Comment: `my_function()` *did not receive any variables* - it received only numeric values, with absolutely no connection to the variables that held them.  It could return something like `"first"`, `"second"`, `"third"` to indicate which value was smallest, but it couldn't possibly return `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` because it has no way of knowing those names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min()` will find minimum value, so it doesn't care about argument name. But `min()` can take also iterable as argument.

```
data = [2, 3, 1]
print(data.index(min(data))
```

With this you will get position of minimum value.

You can also use more sophisticated approach - store some metadata, like name with data:

```
data = [('a', 3), ('b', 0), ('c', 1)]
```

here you have list of tuples, but to find min value you have to let know min what value use for comparison:

```
minValue = min(list(map(lambda x: x[1], data)))
minPosition = list(map(lambda x: x[1], data)).index(minValue)
print(data[minPosition]) # prints ('b', 0)
```

Searching for variable name directly is not advised, someone may refactor something later and your code will be broken. It's better to store more information as data.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a `dict` as a parameter to your function, and set the variable names as the `dict` keys like this:

`d={'a': 78*453, 'b': 654-877, 'c': 98765*785}`

and then get the key name with the min value like this:

```
def my_function(d):
    return min(d, key=d.get)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though its probably not advisable, but since python 3.8 you could work with the new `=` in f-strings.
Take this example:

```
def return_value(a):
    return a

def return_variable_name_with_value(a):
    return f'{a=}'

print(return_value(5))
# Output:
# 5
print(return_variable_name_with_value(5))
# Output:
# a=5
```